# JavaFX Raspberry Pi UI not showing

Tags: java, javafx

When trying to run a JavaFX app from Raspberry Pi B+ device running Raspbian the UI does not show up unlike when running from a PC.

The command invoked was:

```
java -jar app.jar
```

[image]

What could be the problem that the UI does not show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to run with this command:

```
sudo java -Djavafx.platform=eglfb -cp /opt/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:app.jar com.app.MainApp
```

After doing something similar to this:

- Download
  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u73-b02/jdk-8u73-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.gz
- sudo tar zxvf jdk-8u73-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.gz -C /opt ->installs in
  /opt
- sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac
  /opt/jdk1.8.0_73/bin/javac 1
- sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java
  /opt/jdk1.8.0_73/bin/java 1
- sudo update-alternatives --config javac
- sudo update-alternatives --config java
- download
  http://108.61.191.178/downloads/openjfx-8u40-sdk-overlay-linux-armv6hf.zip
- sudo unzip openjfx-8u40-sdk-overlay-linux-armv6hf.zip -d
  /opt/jdk1.8.0_73

Answer (score 0):

I guess the user, who is executing the program, has no reading access on the css files. According to that the GUI can't be loaded.